# C++ Namespaces and header files

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have seen codes with `using namespace std;`. Does it mean that if we use this then we don't have to include header files in the code or if we don't use namespaces, does it mean that we have to use `std::` before every function, class?

Comment: "Does it mean that if we use this then we don't have to include header files" - nope. - "does it mean that we have to use std:: before every function" - yes.

Comment: @Morwenn i am using dev c++ and i don't have to put `std::` before `cin` `cout`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to include header files and use namespaces.

The namespaces are contained in the header files, io streams like `cin`,`cout` are contained in the `namespaces`.So, only if you include the header file, namespace can be used. Without `using namespace std`, You have to use scope resolution operator every time you use those functions.

Comment: @ Aswin Murugesh that's what i was wondering because i am using `cin` `cout` just by including header file `iostream`. I don't use `namespaces`. i am using dev c++.

Comment: @Sireiz: But the same doesnt apply in `g++`, linux compiler. You have to use namespace in g++ , else you will receive errors

Comment: @Sireiz: So namespace usage is compiler oriented

Comment: @Sireiz If you think that this answer helped you then you should not leave it unaccepted.

Comment: @PHIfounder i have mentioned my appreciation to everyone, there is no option here to accept more than one answers and it will be injustice if i accept only one.

Comment: @Sireiz But the one answer with the highest votes seems to be a viable option, so you can accept one and up vote for the others... accepting one of these doesn't seem too difficult in fact its necessary for the betterment of the future users and the post.

Comment: @PHIfounder: Thanks for fighting for my reputation :)

Comment: Boy! `cin`, `cout` aren't functions!

Answer (score 1):

`using namespace std;` means that all names from `std` namespace can be used without specifying their namespace explicitly (with `std::` prefix). That is, after `using namespace std;`, both `string` and `std::string` are valid. Without `using namespace std;`, only `std::string` would work.

Header files still must be included.

Note that usage of `using namespace` is often discouraged as it populates your code with all names from that namespace, and conflicts may occur.

Comment: so you are saying that if i don't use namespace i have to put `std::` even before `cin` or `cout`? but i am using them and i am not `using namespaces' or `std::`.

Comment: Exactly. Maybe your compiler forgives you here (I guess it tries to resolve names in the `std` namespace by default), but C++ standard requires either `using namespace` or explicit namespace specification, and e.g. gcc wouldn't compile your code without `std::`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 using namespace std;
```

Is not really an ideal practice I would apply in a professional code base. The reason is that it practically "opens up" `std` namespace (packages in Java if you like) where you are probably doing "Hello world"ish programming i.e. not so severe as RT Embedded, Mission Critical, or Safety Critical. For example, I work in Interservice/Industry Training and Simulation where things are often safety/mission critical; people will propbably have a quiet word with me if I was using multiple namespaces so openly. It's not really about the size of your program, it is more about *Good practice*. Yes, if you have so many things to use from `std` namespace, then probably you can simply use it. A compromise, and also what I sometimes do, is:

```
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
// And something like that
```

This "exposes" the ones that you will need for this scope and still lets you use:

```
string myStr;
cout << "Some cout" << endl;
```

Like what you mentioned in your question. Why not try that?

A "Good bit" of all is that if you follow the approach I mentioned, it also "Upgrade" your level of knowlege in C++ namespaces and possible STLs.

I know some people will say "Well that is stil hard work" but to me it is a good compromise, *up to a point*. :)

**DON'T FORGET TO ADD THE NECESSARY HEADER FILES PLEASE :-)**